# Selenium Can't click ajax button

Tags: python, selenium

i have a button like this

```
<button data-control-name="more_comments" id="ember1181" class="comments-comments-list__load-more-comments-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" style="" xpath="1"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text" style="">
    Load more comments
</span></button>
```

and it is loaded with ajax.

my code last code is

```
browser.implicitly_wait(50)
browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('comments-comments-list__load-more-comments-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view')[1].click();")
```

i am getting this error oven and over

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined
```

i have tried

```
implicit_wait

WebElementWait

selection by css selector

by xpath
```

but still no improvements

Thanks in advance

Comment: it would be of help if you could proved a minimal reproducible example. Also consider reading the How to Ask page, to increases chance getting a useful answer

Comment: Thanks for your concern.I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

So Id's are dynamic so you can use below solution to handle 1st comment section from your web page:

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/(//button[@data-control-name='comment'])[1]"))).click()
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load more comments']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: i tried this too.i got timeout error, and i tried to increase the wait time.still i am getting
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Comment: Can yo share your url ?

Comment: i am scraping linkedin public page
https://www.linkedin.com/company/bbc-news/
i clicked the comments button with the same code above
after clicking the comments button the load more comments button is loaded through script